# Converting Go struct to string

Tags: xml, struct, go

My Code :

```
type Link struct {
    Href string `xml:"href,attr"`
}

var html Link = ""
func (s Entry) String() string {
  links := string(s.Link)
}
```

I parsed a whole XML document to get the links and text, Now I want to append all the parsed data in `html` variable to construct a nice view on the localhost. But `s.Link` can't be converted to string data type maybe because type conversion only supports basic data-types , Any Solutions ?

Live demo : http://play.golang.org/p/7HRHusXLe2

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Are you just asking how to print a `Link` struct as a string? Have you looked at the `fmt` package?

Comment: I know how to print struct as string but I want to convert it so that I can append all of them in html variable to construct a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you don't want to append the `string` representation of the struct `Link`, you just need its `Href` field which is already of type `string`.

```
func (s Entry) LinkString() string {
    return s.Link.Href
}
```

Also note that if you use a non-pointer receiver `Entry`, your method `LinkString()` will receive a copy of the struct. Which in this case is not a problem, it's just a little slower because a copy has to be made.

If your struct gets bigger, it's better to use pointer receiver: `*Entry`:

```
func (s *Entry) LinkString() string {
    return s.Link.Href
}
```

Also note that you don't even need a method to access the URL text because your fields (`Entry.Link` and `Link.Href`) are exported because they start with an upper-case letter, so you can simply refer to it like this:

```
// e is of type Entry:
url := e.Link.Href
// url is of type string
```